# How to use AndroidViewClient Culebra to scroll down

Tags: python, mobile, androidviewclient

I have a Samsung S3 mini running Android 4.1.2 and AndroidViewVersion 10.0. I try to scroll down in the menu Settings. With the right button on Culebra I can select the option UiScrollable and then select "Fling forward", the device is scrolling down well but the generated script has no codes for scrolling down. Do I miss anything ?

Comment: I try with different position on the scrollable menu but I can't generate any codes related to the scrolling with the context menu UiScrollable even the device is scrolling properly and no error on Culebra. Instead of that I use the context menu "Drag dialog" and it's working with the generated codes device.dragDip(...) and code a loop to scroll down to the needed ViewId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the case you mentioned on a Samsung S4 Android 4.4.2 using **culebra 10.2.0** and it works as expected. In Settings, select **UiScrollable** -> **Fling to end** and the following line is generated

```
android___id_list.uiScrollable.flingToEnd()
```

and the list flings till the end.

Comment: I still have Culebra version 10.0.0, I will upgrade to the latest version and do test again. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: I confirm it's working perfectly after upgrading to version 10.3.0. I prefer to use the UiScrollable methods for a scrollable view as it is totally transparent, no coordinates, really good thanks